# I want to retrive image url in adapter file

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am displaying image on `recyclerView` using modal class and `adapter` class file,
now I want to share images externally and download images on the phone.

but I tried a lot, I am not understanding how to get image URL in adapter file.
Please help me to find a solution.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Data> data;
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(List<Data> data, Context context) {
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_design,parent,false);
        return new ImageAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data data1=data.get(position);
        ImageView imageView=holder.imageView;
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(data1.getImgUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ImageButton share,download;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            share=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.share);
            download=(ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);

            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"url here ");
                    shareIntent.setType("images/*");
                   context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Send Via"));
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                }
            });

            download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: send a list of url or string or array whatever u want from the adapter call in adapter arguments. Thanks

Comment: `data1.getImgUrl()` what is returning ?

Comment: I am fetching from API file. with getter & setter class.
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String imgUrl;

    public Data(int id, String imgUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}

Comment: @HemantParmar it is showing me
http://bjpalerts.in/uploads/profile/image1.png

this link .. on every images.
But when i am sharing direct from url it is not working .

Comment: you have to convert image uri to bitmap, i post the ans have look.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Data data1=data.get(position);
    ImageView imageView=holder.imageView;
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(data1.getImgUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

replace this with

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Data data1=data.get(position);
    ImageView imageView=holder.imageView;
    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,getLocalBitmapUri(getBitmapFromURL(data1.getImgUrl())));
                shareIntent.setType("images/*");
                shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Send Via"));

            }
        });


    Glide.with(context)
            .load(data1.getImgUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

also add

```
  public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

and

```
 fun getBitmapFromURL(strURL: String): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        val url = URL(strURL)
        val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.doInput = true
        connection.connect()
        val input = connection.inputStream
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input)
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks but this is showing me


android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

But I already added na Flag Activity

Comment: can you send me the code where you fill the adapter

Comment: you are giving me some function in java. some in kotlin.

Comment: sorry but i was working on both so didn't convert the other one...and where did you posted the code ..i couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

You are getting image url from list, before share you have to Use `Picasso` to load the url into a Bitmap. after that

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     shareItem(data1.getImgUrl()) 
                }
            });


    public void shareItem(String url) {
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(new Target() {
            @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Your Image"));
            }
            @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) { }
            @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) { }
        });
    }
```

Convert `Bitmap` into `URi`:

```
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Hope it will help you!!

Comment: No, it is showing me to implements all Target() methods , 


and data1=data.getimgurl() is not working